# Baby Rudin 1.21 $0\leq t<1\rightarrow t^n\leq t$ and $0<y_1<y_2\rightarrow y_1^n<y_2^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

On page $10$, Rudin makes the following assertions

> 1. If $0\leq t<1$ then $t^n\leq t$.
> 2. If $0<y_1<y_2$, then $y_1^n<y_2^n$.

Now, I understand this is true, but I can't get the grasp of how we can prove this with the previous content in the book, there are some propositions about multiplication and inequalities, but they proved not useful.

Does anyone know how to prove this fact **with the content available in the book up to page 10**?

I think both of these could be proved using induction, but I don't think that's available yet, as Rudin hasn't used it up to this point.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that $t$ had to be $\geq 0$.

Comment: Alright, can you show that $0\le x\le y$ implies $0\le tx\le ty$?

Comment: Take a look at Proposition 1.18.

Comment: @justanotherhagman Yes, I thought I could use that to say that $t\leq 1\rightarrow t^2\leq t\rightarrow \cdots\rightarrow t^n\leq t^{n-1}\leq \cdots \leq t$, but I thought I'd need induction to fill in the "..." Details, and I'm not sure if induction is available yet, as Rudin hasn't used it so far.

Comment: The very irritating thing about Rudin, is he doesn't specify what you can and can't use.  The student is confronting for the very first time that she can't use her basic assumptions.  But here's what I figured:  Rudin is formulizing the Real numbers as a complete ordered field.  That must be treated as new.  Everything else, logic and *arithmetic of indexing notation* can be assumed.  It can be assumed very glibly.  So induction is fine (he's *never* going to define it).  .. more to come ....

Comment: On page 6 he very quickly states "one usually writes" $x^2$ for $x\cdot x$.  And that's it.  *That* is the entirity of exponents to integer powers.  Then in excercise 6.  He wants you to expand the definition to rational powers and then to real powers and always show the definitions are well defined and $b^{x+y} = b^xb^y$.  *But he never showed that for integer powers*   In fact $b^n; n \le 1$ was never defined.  After several readings I determined that $b^n$ is just notation and the n is simple *counting*.  From that Rudin assumes $b^nb^m=b^{n+m}$ is simply a matter of counting and writing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I agree with your vision: For proving theorem 1.20 it seems he uses the well-ordering principle (see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476689/baby-rudin-theorem-1-20-b-proof) or induction, but that was not really clear to me. According to your comment on $x^2 = x\cdot x$, I think that's not really refering to exponentiation per se, I think it's like when we have a group in which we denote the law of composition by $+$, we write $2a$ for $a+a$, not meaning the product of $2$ with $a$, because there may not even be a $2$ in our group.

Comment: @fleablood This book is making me crazy: right after proving that every positive number has an $n$-th root, he starts 'taking square roots' on both sides of inequalities (proving the triangle inequality for complex numbers, for example) with no justification as to why that's ok!

Comment: I hated Rudin when I first read it but I really, really like it now.  You have to read and read it again  Taking the square root of both sides is okay.  For b >0 and c > 0 then $b^{1/2} < c^{1/2} <=> b = {b^{1/2}}^2 < b^{1/2}c^{1/2} < c^{1/2}c^{1/2} = c$.

Comment: That was my point about $x^2 = x\cdot x$  The 2 is simply an index and therefore we don't *have* to prove $b^{n+m}=b^nb^m$ as that's a consequence of *writing*.  But $b^{m/n}$ *is* a definition and relies on properties of the real.  It's bit subtle.  And glib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Prop 1.18 b**
>
> If $x > 0$ and $y < z$ then $xy < xz$

$$0 \le t < 1\text{ so }0 = 0\cdot t \le t\cdot t = t^2 < 1\cdot t = t$$

For any $\,t^{n-1} < t$, $t^n = t^{n-1}t < t^2 < t$. So the result follows inductively.

2) is similar.  $y_1 < y_2$ so $y_1^2 < y_1y_2 < y_2^2$ and the rest follows inductively.

Comment: Even though this answer uses induction, the author has given details in the comments.