# Question about Baby Rudin — Theorem 1.20 b)

Tags: real-analysis

I won't reproduce the proof here, but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476689/baby-rudin-theorem-1-20-b-proof) is a link to another MathSE question about the same theorem. I've read Brian M. Scott's answer, but I think I'm missing something — I still don't understand why $m_1$ and $m_2$ are necessary for the proof; why can't we just pick an $m$ like in the following examples?

$$
\text{Let } m = 
\begin{cases}
5 &\text{if } nx = 4.6 \\
2 &\text{if } nx = \sqrt{2} \\
-6 &\text{if } nx = -7 \\
\vdots &\text{etc.}
\end{cases} ,
$$

i.e. let $m$ be the next largest integer. I believe this method will always satisfy $m - 1 \leq nx < m$.

Now I'm guessing that the reason we can't directly pick an $m$ without the help of $m_1$ and $m_2$ has something to do with rigour; I think I would be assuming things about $\mathbb{R}$ that Rudin wouldn't want me to just yet, but I can't quite put my finger on what exactly.

Comment: Which theorem or proposition are you using to construct $m$? What's etc mean? The reader just learned what + and < meant, what's this funny dot between 4 and 6? and why is there a roof on 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at that point we don’t know that there **is** a next larger integer. As I said in that answer, we could use the well-ordering principle for the natural numbers to show that such an integer exists **if** we knew that $nx$ was positive, but we don’t: $n$ is positive, but $x$ can be any real number. The argument using $m_1$ and $m_2$ establishes that there is such an $m$ even if $nx$ is negative. This part of the proof of could just as well have been pulled out as a separate lemma or proposition: for any $x\in\Bbb R$ there is in integer $m$ such that $m-1\le x<m$.

Comment: I should've asked a more specific question. I feel like the $m_1, m_2$ method is just a more complicated way to note that $\mathbb{Z}$ is unbounded in both the positive and negative directions — a corollary from part a), I suppose. Then just choose $m$ and $m - 1$ from all of $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than from the subset in your other answer. Is this method not simpler/more elegant?

Comment: @JeremyLindsay: That’s irrelevant, since it’s not justifiable on the basis of what has been developed at that point in the text. I don’t see any legitimate approach that’s any simpler than the one that Walter used. (And in my experience — his wife Mary Ellen was my thesis adviser — he was not given to unnecessary complexity.)