# Baby Rudin 1.20(b) Proof—Alternative Justification

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

This question is based on a [previously asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476689/baby-rudin-theorem-1-20-b-proof) one that I will quote in full here:

---

I have a question about Rudin's proof of Theorem 1.20 (b) in his book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.  Theorem 1.20 is stated as follows:

> (a) If $x\in\Bbb{R}, y\in\Bbb{R}$, and $x>0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $$nx>y.$$
> (b) If $x\in\Bbb{R}, y\in\Bbb{R}$, and $x<y$, then there exists a $p\in Q$ such that $x<p<y$.

I understand Rudin's proof of (a).  The beginning of Rudin's proof of (b) is given below:

> Since $x<y$, we have $y-x>0$, and (a) furnishes a positive integer $n$ such that $$n(y-x)>1.$$  Apply (a) again, to obtain positive integers $m_1$ and $m_2$ such that $m_1>nx$, $m_2>-nx$.  Then $$-m_2<nx<m_1.$$  Hence there is an integer $m$ (with $-m_2\leq m\leq m_1$) such that $$m-1\leq nx<m.$$

I don't understand the justification for this last sentence beginning "Hence...."  How is $m$ found, and why are $m_1$ and $m_2$ needed to find $m$?

---

I want to know if my justification for why such an $m$ exists is correct. We are given that $-m_2<nx<m_1$, and we want to show that
$$
\exists m \in[-m_2,m_1](m-1\le nx < m) \, .
$$
We can proceed by contradiction. Suppose that
$$
\forall m \in[-m_2,m_1](nx\not\in[m-1,m)) \, .
$$
This means that
\begin{align}
x &\not\in [-m_2-1,-m_2) \\
x &\not\in [-m_2,-m_2+1) \\
x &\not\in [-m_2+1,-m_2+2) \\
\vdots \\
x &\not\in[m_1-2,m_1-1) \\
x &\not\in[m_1-1,m_1) \\
x &\not\in[m_1,m_1+1) \, .\\
\end{align}
Putting these statements together, we get that $x\not\in[-m_2-1,m_1+1)$, and so it is not true that $-m_2<nx<m_1$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: The need for $m_1$ and $m_2$ is to indicate that $m$ is not any integer. And you justification is correct. You just created a partition of the original set, so the element $nx$ must belong to one and only one of them.